# WebdriverIO - Run the same code parallelly on Android and iOS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I'm working on the mobile automation and I need to run the same spec in both Andorid and iOS parallelly. But the locators are not same in both Android and iOS app.

Is it possible for me to define the two locators in the page.js for a single element?

something similar to Selenium+Appium using the annotation AndroidFindBy and iOSFindBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a option to do it in the WebdriverIO

```
get username() {
    const selectorAndroid = 'new UiSelector().text("Cancel").className("android.widget.Button")'
    const selectorIOS = 'UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()[0]'
    const selectorType = driver.isAndroid ? 'android' : 'ios'
    const selector = driver.isAndroid ? selectorAndroid : selectorIOS
    return $(`${selectorType}=${selector}`)
}
```

Reference : [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/browserobject/)